# continuous functions on a singleton

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ be the continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space with values in $\mathbb{C}$. What is $C(\{\ast\},\mathbb{C})$, i.e. the continuous functions where the compact Hausdorff space is a singleton?

It consists only the constant function $\{\ast\}\to \mathbb{C}, \ast\mapsto \lambda$ for a fixed, arbitrary $\lambda$.

Thus, is $C(\{\ast\})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ as metric spaces $\big(C(\{\ast\})$ endowed with the metric induced by the sup-norm, and $\mathbb{C}$ with the standard metric$\big)$) or is it wrong?

Comment: I edited my question because I think I wasn't precise enough, at first.

Answer (score 1):

These are the only maps from your (somewhat trivial) metric space to $\mathbb{C}$ at all! They are continuous somewhat trivially since there is only one point in the metric space, and so all the distances are $0$, and $|f(\star) - f(\star)| = 0$ always holds.

Answer (score 1):

From the topological view we know that a function  $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ iff for every open set $U \subset Y$ such that $f(x_0) \in U$ we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $X$

Now if we a trivial metric space $(\{x\},d)$, then for every open subset $U$of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $f(x)$ we have that $f^{-1}(U)=\{x\}$ which is open because the whole space is always open.(and closed)

Comment: thank you. can $C(point,\mathbb{C})$ be identified with $\mathbb{C}$?